# Error LNK 2019 unresolved external symbol from header file from my professor

Tags: c++

So I'm pretty new to C++ programming and am taking a class on it but am having some trouble with an assignment because I am getting an error I can't seem to fix. The assignment is to create a composite class out of a number of classes using a string class the professor gave us. The problem I'm having is that I'm getting an unresolved external symbol error from the header file he gave us and I don't know why. I added the folder containing the header file and the associated cpp file using Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories and then used #include  in the header file for my class but I'm getting 2 errors when I try to build it, the program compiles just fine. It's strange that I'm only getting 2 errors when there are many more functions in WCS_String that don't return an error.

Here are the error codes I'm getting:

```
1>Name.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall WCS_String::~WCS_String(void)" (??1WCS_String@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function __unwindfunclet$??0Name@@QAE@XZ$0

1>Name.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __thiscall WCS_String::LocalCopy(char const *)" (?LocalCopy@WCS_String@@AAEXPBD@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall WCS_String::WCS_String(char const *)" (??0WCS_String@@QAE@PBD@Z)
```

If anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated as I have run into a dead end with my limited programming knowledge. If you need any more information in order to help me please just ask.

Comment: Did your professor give you .cpp files as well?

Comment: Yes it is in the same directory as the header file. Do I need to do anything with the cpp file to include it as well?

Comment: Actually if I were you I would just copy all the professor files to the project directory, and add both header and source files to it.

Comment: Ah that seems to have fixed it. Thank you so much. I'll have to ask the professor what I was doing wrong in linking to the files next time, but it all seems to be working fine now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would just copy all the professor files to the project directory, and add both header and source files to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have .o or .obj files associated with your WCS_String class, you need to tell your linker where to find them.